# PHP: trying to make a search engine for my website

Tags: php, search-engine

I am trying to make a search engine for my website. It works pretty good if I enter a single word as search query like `foo` or `bar`. The problem is it fails when I enter two or more words like `foo bar`.

How should I deal with such words? Splitting the words (using `explode`) and then look for each word in the table for indexed words? This doesn't sound like a good idea

I am using `GET` method for this search engine.

```
<?php
if($_GET['query']){
    $search = $_GET['query'];
    $search = strip_tags($search);
    $search = trim($search);
    $search = addslashes( strtolower($search));

echo $search;
$start = microtime();
$searchquery = mysql_query("SELECT sw_wordid FROM tbl_search_word WHERE sw_word LIKE '%$search%'");
                               //tbl_search_word contains all the indexed words

$searchrow = mysql_fetch_array($searchquery);   
$end = microtime();

echo $searchrow['sw_wordid'].'<br />';
echo $end - $start;
}
```

?>

Comment: are you using get? post? or something else?

Comment: I would suggest looking into something like Zend_Search_Lucene

Comment: @RickyMason I am using GET

Comment: well, whats your code look like?

Comment: @RickyMason , you can see the code. I will make an edit to explain it

Comment: `Splitting the words (using explode) and then look for each word in the table for indexed words? This doesn't sound like a good idea` Why not? you have to split them up in any case in order to look for either of them

Comment: When you type "foo bar" what do you expect your engine to fetch? Entries with any of "foo" and "bar" (OR) or the exact "foo bar" match?

Comment: @vrazorf this could would work pretty well if I wannna search `foo bar`. Thats, obvious, that I want to search `foo` and `bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I agree with Hanky Panky splitting it is not by itself a bad option you can try that, but as nobody else help you with some other alternative I give you one more, it's not so effective when searching many keywords and depending on what you want as a result.

First of all I beg you properly santinize properly your input DO NOT just put what the user gives you in the string like the code you posted, never do that, you will be probably opening a security hole for sql inyection.
Try prpared statments using either PDO or mysqli.

Can you try this:

```
$searchquery = mysql_query("
SELECT sw_wordid FROM tbl_search_word WHERE INSTR(sw_word,'$search')>0
");
```

And you can share your benchmark with use to help you improve it but not knowing exactly what you want for the result, the alternative you choose may depend on it.

Please share your results.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the space you entered is taken as %20 so an error occurs why not use str_replace("%20", " ",$query);

hope it helps